# macOS, is it possible to terminate a single python thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminate

I am running a long computation on a Jupyter notebook and one of the threads spawn by python (a `pickle.dump` call, I suspect) took all the available RAM making the system clunky.

Now, I would like to terminate the single thread. Interrupting the notebook does not work and I would like not to restart the notebook in order to don't lose all the calculations made so far. If I open the Activity Monitor I can clearly see one python process which contains multiple threads.

I know I can terminate the whole process, but is there a way to terminate a single thread?

Comment: You want to terminate the thread from the running code are you expecting to terminate the thread externally from the OS?

Comment: @Francesco From the OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can kill a thread of a process outside the process itself:

As reported in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1071/210584)

> Threads are an integral part of the process and cannot be killed
>   outside it. There is the `pthread_kill` function but it only applies in
>   the context of the `thread itself`. From the docs at the link

Comment: I suspected that, how unfortunate. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Nice question though it made me think about it :)

Answer (score -1):

Of course the answer is yes, I have a demo code FYI(not secure):

```
from threading import Thread
import time


class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, stop):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stop = stop

    def run(self):
        stop = False
        while not stop:
            print("I'm running")
            time.sleep(1)
            # if the signal is stop, break `while loop` so the thread is over.
            stop = self.stop

m = MyThread(stop=False)
m.start()
while 1:
    i = input("input S to stop\n")
    if i == "S":
        m.stop = True
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: This would not solve the problem. I want to stop the currently running thread, not implement a new one.

Comment: And you definitely want to use Events or similar